# Не показывается background-image через css

Tags: html, css

Есть код HTML:
`<div class="header-image">123</div>`

CSS: `.header-image {background-image: url(/images/header-image.png);}`
который должен тянуть картинку из папки images, но он этого не делает, видно только 123

Пробовал `url('/images/header-image.png');` `url('../images/header-image.png');`

Расположение файлов
---images
----header-image.png
---styles
----style.css
--index.html

Директория находится выше

Comment: Вариант url('/images/header-image.png'); - искать папку images от корня сайта
url('../images/header-image.png'); - выйти на один уровень вверх от того места, где находится  ваш css-файл и искать папку images уже там
url(./images/header-image.png); или url(images/header-image.png); - искать папку images прямо в той же папке, где и css-файл.

Comment: А что в консоли пишет, нет файла такого?

Comment: @Quazimorda напишите такой же ответ, я проставлю как решение
Спасибо!

Answer (score 0):

```
CSS: .header-image {background-image: url(images/header-image.png);}
```

Answer (score 0):

Варианты указания пути:
url('/images/header-image.png'); - искать папку images от корня сайта url('../images/header-image.png'); - выйти на один уровень вверх от того места, где находится ваш css-файл и искать папку images уже там
url(./images/header-image.png); или url(images/header-image.png); - искать папку images прямо в той же папке, где и css-файл.